# How to set adjusted white balance as start position for lightroom presets

Tags: lightroom, white-balance

As example, after import i have image with temp=3400, then i have decreased temp to 3000, but when i'm trying apply some preset, preset increases not adjusted value(3000), but value(3400).

So, question is how to make adjusted white-balance as default for preset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A preset can either change a setting to a specific value or leave it as it is.

A quick and easy way to have the preset not touch the white balance is the following:

1. Apply the preset to an image.
2. Right click the preset's name in the Presets pane and choose 'Update with Current Settings'. In the dialogue that pops up, **untick** 'White Balance'. Close the Dialogue with 'Update'.

Alternatively, if you want a new preset (instead of changing the existing one), at step 2, instead of 'Update with Current Settings', hit the plus button in the upper right of the Presets pane and create a new preset from there. The same dialogue will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying preset, then set the temperature by hand and save this as new preset. On the next image apply this new preset.

Comment: I do not want to change preset, because problem is not caused by preset. Problem in photo, which white balance is wrong. Also i want to choose one preset from a list and each one will be more warm than needed

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want presets with relative values, a functionality a lot of users want but which is not currently available in LR.

Comment: Yeah, exactly it. It's sad that there is no such functionality. Also found [this](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/relative_presets_would_save_the_day) and it is still under consideration